# VBA - How to keep code from executing while flipping between report views

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using a report like a template for similar projects.  I have code formatting it when it opens.  Problem is, the code executes when switching to Print Preview view.  Some formatting the code does is not allowed in that view.

I've got around the problem by putting an invisible textbox, named "txtFormatted" in my report.  My code populates it, once done formatting, with "True".  The module won't execute while the textbox has that value.

But this solution seems sloppy.  What do people do to have code execute when opening a report but not to run again when flipping through views?

Comment: Why are you switching between views?

Comment: User is clicking a button on the Navigation form.  The DoCmd is can't open the file in Print Preview view without restricting formatting options.  So it has to be opened in normal view.  When the user switches view to print the document, it runs the formatting code again, creating errors because of the formatting restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a textbox, use a private variable (private to the report) in the top of the report's code module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private IsFormatted As Boolean
```

It will be *False* when opening the report.
Then set this to *True* as you do now, and check this variable before running the formatting code.

Comment: Ty Gustav. Basic programing: the Global like private variable at the top of the report code.  I am rusty.